# openResty fails to write log header

Tags: nginx, lua, nginx-reverse-proxy, openresty

I have the following configuration to write logs to access.log

## START Header logging with LUA with Masking

```
    set $resp_header "";
    header_filter_by_lua_block {
        local rh = ngx.resp.get_headers()
        for k, v in pairs(rh) do
            ngx.var.resp_header = ngx.var.resp_header .. k.."="..v.." "
        end}
```

## END Header logging with LUA with Masking

This works fine for most of my upstream responses. but for the one that sends duplicate header of the same name "Set-Cookie" and both are pretty lengthy in number of characters. nginx error log says .

[error] 3142684#3142684: *790582 failed to run header_filter_by_lua*: header_filter_by_lua:11: attempt to concatenate local 'v' (a table value)

I am looking into all possible LUA documentation. Any help will be appreciated.

As a workaround I have set the header "Set-Cookie" forcefully in nginx.

#---
for k, v in pairs(rh) do
if k:lower() == ("set-cookie") then
v="REDACTED"
end
#---

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of the headers are allowed to repeat (`Set-Cookie` is one of them) and will be returned as a table by `get_headers()` function, which your code doesn't take into account (hence the error you're getting).

Replace `ngx.var.resp_header .. k.."="..v.." "` with something like `ngx.var.resp_header .. k.."="..(type(v) == "table" and table.concat(v, ";") or v).." "`

Comment: Thanks Paul. It worked perfect. Can you please help with the documentation or blog which has these information.

Comment: This is captured in the [get_headers() documentation](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module#ngxreqget_headers); see the paragraph that starts with "For multiple instances of request headers such as:..."